# IQueryable<T>.Contains Expression Tree with Expression parameter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression

I want to implement custom `.Contains()` method with the following syntax:

```cs
static IQueryable<T> IsContainedBy<T, K>(this IQueryable<T> source, List<K> items, Expression<Func<T, K>> exp)
```

This method should look for coincidence in `items` array. `Expression<Func<T, K>> exp` provides property of object to be used for comparison. I have written the following code:

```cs
private IQueryable<T> WhereIsContainedBy<T, K>(IQueryable<T> source, List<K> items, Expression<Func<T, K>> exp) {
   if (items == null || items.Count == 0)
        return source;
   MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(List<K>).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(K) });

   MethodCallExpression a = 
        Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(items), containsMethod, new Expression[] { exp.Body
                   /* Expression.Constant("31212eb5-cd5d-4f77-858a-a7ddba8e3d2c")*/ });

   Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(a, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));

   return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

But i get the following error:

```
var source = new List<string>() { "31212eb5-cd5d-4f77-858a-a7ddba8e3d2c" };
var r = WhereIsContainedBy(_context.StageActions, source, a => a.StageActionId);
var a = await r.ToListAsync();

---

Where(s => List<string> { "31212eb5-cd5d-4f77-858a-a7ddba8e3d2c", }.Contains(a.StageActionId))' could not be translated.
```

But if I use commented `Expression.Constant.....` it works just fine.

Comment: My guess would be you are creating a lambda with a new `Expression.Parameter` instead of using the one from `exp.Body` so effectively you have `s => List.Contains(a.StageActionId)`. You need to pass `exp.Parameters[0]` to the `Lambda` creation method. Not sure why replacing `List<>` with `String` and calling `List<T>.Contains` doesn't cause another error.

Comment: @NetMage, Oh.... thank you. It works!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I got the

Method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' declared on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' cannot be called with instance of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.Int32]' 

error with this code. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reusing parameter from selector expression (i.e. `exp`) instead of creating a new one for resulting expression :

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(a, exp.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: Guru Stron, thank You for Yours answer, I appreciate it. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Ignatella was glad to help!